# how to activate all the ksoftirqds in linux? (about net stack of linux kernel)

Tags: linux, performance, networking, kernel, irq

I have a multiqueue NIC card on a 4-cores intel machine and
I bind every queue of the NIC card on a cpu core (set /proc/irq/xxx/smp_affinity)
Let's say queue0 on core0, queue1 on core1 and so on.

It is said that the softirq will invoke on the same core that the hardware interrupt occured.
Why the ksoftirqd can not run parellelly on my machine?
It's just one kernel thread (like ksoftirqd/2) that will use 100% of a core but others are 0%

when I use

```
cat /proc/interrupts | grep eth1
```

I can see that all packages are even distributed to all the NIC queues.

update:

Here is a solution for the 100% softirq problem if you can read Chinese
http://hi.baidu.com/higkoo/item/42ba6c353bc8aed76d15e9c3 (please see #7)
if not, which blog says that you can add a another card, this problem would be solved

Answer (score 3):

ksoftirqd doesn't need to run parallel because it doesn't normally run the softirqs. All softirqs are normally run on the CPU where they were requested right after the interrupt that requested them.

softirqs will be run on ksoftirqd only in case of a "softirq" flood - after the kernel executes an interrupt, it checks if it needs to run anu softirqs. If it does it will run them. During the time that these runs interrupts are enabled, so it is possible that when you were running the softirqs an interrupt occurs that marked them for running again. This is why the kernel will again check for market softirqs after running them.

It should be obvious that given a flood of interrupts this can turn into a live lock very fast - where all we do is run softirqs and interrupt and never any user code. This is why the kernel has a "damper" mechanism - if after 10 times of checking if any softirqs are marked after running them they are still marked, the kernel will not run softirqs at end of the interrupt and instead wake up the special kernel thread ksoftirqd to run them until the flood is over.

This is a watchdog mechanism to handle IRQ floods and most of the time it is dormant, so having a multi threaded ksoftirqd will not really help your in the normal case.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is there a solution for the exactly 'flood' case ?

Comment: @dilfish yes, changing the kernel code. This is why it is open source :-)

Answer (score 0):

ksoftirqd is the base of all polling routines in the kernel, including the polling of the network queues of your card.

As such, the triggering of ksoftirqd will affect how well it threads. 
The fact is that it doesn't thread at all. This is because the timer triggering ksoftirqd is always delivered to the same core.

But, you ask this question with a goal in mind. It might make sense to talk about that goal first, not about this detail of the implementation towards that goal.

Comment: ok, my question is why it has 100% in a core and 0% in other 3 cores, I want all of the 100% even distributed on 4 cores, each with 25%.